# Old box of fridge Arm and Hammer baking soda

Tags: plumbing

I have an old box of baking soda from the fridge. Now, a couple of home repair folks told me I can just dump it into my kitchen drain to keep the drain clear and deodorizer to get rid of it. Is this true? And if so, can someone tell me what the steps are to do it properly? I am a first time owner and don't know much to be honest. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baking soda dumped in the sink drain with a little water or down the toilet and flushed would not hurt your plumbing it will dissolve as water mixes with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and I think box side mentions how to.
Incase not I or should say my wife, just pours about half a box down each drain side adds a cup or two of water.  Lets it set for about ten minutes then rinses.